# Conditionally Hide Fields On the Page Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to enter into console on the page below code and it needs to go through each value class div element, check if the number inside the value element is more than 500, and if so, hide that element's whole div. To be clear, .listItem is parent of .value. So, if .value's text is more than 500, hide the whole .listItem element it's in.

.listItem > .value

```
$(".value").each(function(){
        if(($(".value").text()) > 500){
            $(".listItem").css("display", "none");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".value").each(function(){
    if (Number($(this).text()) > 500){
        $(this).closest(".listitem").hide();
    }
});
```

should do what you want